# QR code generator for email using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, https, qr-code, react-qr-code

So I am trying to generate QR code using react-qr-code module in the value field I gave `mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${body}` format but when I scan using google lens it's getting converted to https://mailto:_______ which will not work how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mailto:${encodeURIComponent(email)}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}`

will work